# Can i deploy my mini search engine with java Httpserver?

Tags: java, server, httpserver, web-development-server

I have completed all steps of my mini search engine on wikipedia pages in Java, except the last step which is "deployment" on a server and i'm stuck there cause iam not used to web development , so it's an Html page with a form having an input which is the query to search and a submit button to click on to display the result as html links :

For example my java program returns the result : Football ,
so my server should return when i click on the search button of the form a link to Football wikipedia page : [Football](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Football)

i have created a server with java httpserver (i don't know if it's a good choice since iam not a web devloper) that send a html page with the search form and that work , here is the code :

```
  public class server{

     public static class myHttpHandler implements HttpHandler {
         
     
     public void handle(HttpExchange exchange) throws IOException {
         
         Headers header = exchange.getResponseHeaders();
            header.add("Content-Type", "text/html");
            sendIndexFile(exchange);
            
         
        

         
        }}

     
     static private void sendIndexFile(HttpExchange httpExchange) throws IOException
     {
         File indexFile = new File("/SearchEngine/Welcome.html");
         byte [] indexFileByteArray = new byte[(int)indexFile.length()];

         BufferedInputStream requestStream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(indexFile));
         requestStream.read(indexFileByteArray, 0, indexFileByteArray.length);

         httpExchange.sendResponseHeaders(200, indexFile.length());
         OutputStream responseStream = httpExchange.getResponseBody();
         responseStream.write(indexFileByteArray, 0, indexFileByteArray.length);
         responseStream.close();
     }

     private static String getStringFromInputStream(java.io.InputStream inputStream) {

            BufferedReader br = null;
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            try {

                br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (br != null) {
                    try {
                        br.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
            return sb.toString();
        }
     
     

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
     
      HttpServer myserver = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(8700), 0);
      myserver.createContext("/", new myHttpHandler());
      myserver.start();
}}
```

and im stuck here due to multiple problems :

1)- How to get the text entered in the input search form to pass it to my Java program ?

2)- How to structurate my other handlers to get results efficiently ? since my Java program have to load 4 HashMaps to calculate results ( map for PageRank of pages , map of TF , IDF) that takes 2 minutes to load , and after that a search is done in only 5 seconds , so i need to loads the 4 Maps only once ( before ?) when the server starts and after that each search will takes me 5 seconds .

3)- is there another server tool that can make me program this easier ?

Here is the code of my program that display results ( page titles ) in command line :

```
Score s = new Score();
            HashMap<String[], Double> map = new HashMap<String[], Double>();
            map = s.HashMapFromTextFileTF();
            HashMap<String, Double> map2 = new HashMap<String, Double>();
            map2 = s.HashMapFromTextFileIDF();
            HashMap<Integer, Double> mapPageRank = new HashMap<Integer, Double>();
            mapPageRank = HashMapFromTextFilePageRank();



 // Up to here it takes 2 minutes to load
// From here it takes 5 to 10 seconds
ArrayList<String> req = new ArrayList<>(); // This is the query list of words
            int a = 1 ;
            String mot = "";
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);  
            while(a == 1) {
                System.out.println("Enter a query word :");
                mot = scan.next();  
                req.add(mot);
                System.out.println("Another word ?");
                a = scan.nextInt();
                
            }
            
            
            Map<String, List<Integer>> ar = fileToMap("page_word_relation.txt",req);
            ArrayList<Integer> sharedPages =  intersectionWords(req, ar);
            
            
            
            HashMap<Integer, Double> mapScores = new HashMap<Integer, Double>();
            mapScores = scoreFinal(mapPageRank,s.PageScore(sharedPages,req,map,map2));
            
            HashMap<Integer,String> myIndexMap = new HashMap<Integer,String>();
            myIndexMap = HashMapFromTextFilePageId();
            
            
            
            List<Integer> idResultat = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 
            System.out.println("Results of search :");
            
            HashMap<Integer, Double> res = sortPages(mapScores);
            int stop = 0;
            for (Map.Entry<Integer,Double> entry : res.entrySet()) {
                //storing the best 20 ranked pages
                idResultat.add(entry.getKey());
                stop++;
                if(stop == 20)
                        break;
            } 
            
            for(int id : idResultat) {
                
                System.out.println(myIndexMap.get(id)); // Here i print result page titles
            }
          
            
            
            
            System.out.println("completed");
            }
            catch(IOException e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
```

Comment: By “`HttpServer`”, do you mean [`com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/jdk.httpserver/com/sun/net/httpserver/HttpServer.html)?

Comment: @BasilBourque Yes exactly , i searched how to deploy my search engine on a server , i found that tool and i tried it , i don't know if it's good or not since i done just little web dev tasks in my life

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, be aware that [`com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/jdk.httpserver/com/sun/net/httpserver/HttpServer.html) has been reworked to be the new *Simple Web Server* bundled in [Java 18](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_18). See [*JEP 408: Simple Web Server*](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/408).

Neither of these web servers were meant for production use. They are for convenient use by students learning programming, for quick and easy experimentation, and perhaps for deployment in a small in-house non-mission-critical app.

In the Java ecosystem, you have a wealth of choices in robust enterprise-quality web servers for production use.

- The first two obvious choices are [Apache Tomcat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Tomcat) and [Eclipse Jetty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jetty_(web_server)), basically equivalent products aimed at web serving both static pages and dynamic content via [Jakarta Servlet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jakarta_Servlet) & [Jakarta Server Pages (JSP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jakarta_Server_Pages) technology. (Formerly known as *Java Servlet* & *JavaServer Pages*.)
- Several more products add to to that functionality any of the [dozens of enterprise-oriented features](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/) specified by the [Jakarta EE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jakarta_EE). Products include Eclipse Glassfish, Payara, Apache TomEE, Red Hat WildFly & JBoss, IBM OpenLiberty & WebSphere, and [more](https://jakarta.ee/compatibility/).

You said:

> 3)- is there another server tool that can make me program this easier ?

I suggest you rejigger your app to be a Jakarta Servlet or a JSP, for deployment on one of the [web container](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_container) products listed above.

You said:

> since my Java program have to load 4 HashMaps to calculate results ( map for PageRank of pages , map of TF , IDF) that takes 2 minutes to load , and after that a search is done in only 5 seconds , so i need to loads the 4 Maps only once ( before ?) when the server starts

The [*Jakarta Servlet* specification](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/) provides a hook for you to run code when your web app first spins up. (But be aware that the spec leaves it to the implementation to decide to run the hook ahead of time or only after receiving the first client request.)

Your Servlet-based web app is [known in the spec](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/5.0/jakarta-servlet-spec-5.0.html#servlet-context) as a "Servlet Context". To use that hook when your web app first starts and finally ends, write a little class that implements [`ServletContextListener`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/5.0/apidocs/jakarta/servlet/servletcontextlistener). Write your initialization code in the [`contextInitialized`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/5.0/apidocs/jakarta/servlet/servletcontextlistener#contextInitialized(jakarta.servlet.ServletContextEvent)) method, and write your clean up code in the [`contextDestroyed`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/5.0/apidocs/jakarta/servlet/servletcontextlistener#contextDestroyed(jakarta.servlet.ServletContextEvent)) method.

In that `contextInitialized` method is the place to build your cache of `HashMap` data for later use when your Servlet runs every time in response to a client request.

The [`@WebListener`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/5.0/apidocs/jakarta/servlet/annotation/weblistener) annotation flags this class as being special. The servlet container will automatically notice, load, and execute your `contextInitialized` & `contextDestroyed` methods at the appropriate times. This annotation is an alternative to editing configuration files.

```java
package work.basil.example.hello;

import jakarta.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
import jakarta.servlet.ServletContextListener;
import jakarta.servlet.annotation.WebListener;

@WebListener
public class MyServletContextListener implements ServletContextListener
{
    @Override
    public void contextInitialized ( ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent )
    {
        // Build your HashMap data cache here.
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed ( ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent )
    {
        // Do your shutdown and clean-up work here.
    }
}
```

I have written on this several times here on Stack Overflow, as have many others. Search to learn more.

Here is an example where we create a `Map` in the context listener.

We store the map as an attribute in the context object. Context attributes are like a map in that they are a key-value pairing. But the key must be a `String`, and the value is stored as an `Object` object — no [Java Generics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java), so we must cast after retrieval as seen further below in the example servlet code.

```java
package work.basil.example.report;

import jakarta.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
import jakarta.servlet.ServletContextListener;
import jakarta.servlet.annotation.WebListener;

import java.time.DayOfWeek;
import java.util.Map;

@WebListener
public class MyServletContextListener implements ServletContextListener
{
    @Override
    public void contextInitialized ( ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent )
    {
        // Build your HashMap data cache here.
        System.out.println( "INFO - contextInitialized" );
        Map < String, DayOfWeek > employeeWorkDayAssigned =
                Map.of(
                        "Alice" , DayOfWeek.WEDNESDAY ,
                        "Bob" , DayOfWeek.MONDAY ,
                        "Carol" , DayOfWeek.TUESDAY
                );
        servletContextEvent.getServletContext().setAttribute( "work.basil.example.employeeWorkDayAssigned" , employeeWorkDayAssigned );
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed ( ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent )
    {
        // Do your shutdown and clean-up work here.
    }
}
```

And a servlet which uses that `Map` to write a table to a HTML page.

```java
package work.basil.example.report;

import jakarta.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.time.DayOfWeek;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.format.TextStyle;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Map;

@WebServlet ( name = "report", value = "/" )
public class ReportServlet extends HttpServlet
{
    private String message;

    public void init ( )
    {
        message = "Report";
    }

    public void doGet ( HttpServletRequest request , HttpServletResponse response ) throws IOException
    {
        response.setContentType( "text/html" );

        // Hello
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println( "<html lang='en'>" );
        out.println( "<head>" );
        out.println( "<meta charset='UTF-8'>" );
        String css =
                """
                                
                table, th, td , caption {
                    border: 0.5px solid DarkSlateGrey ;
                }
                table {
                    width: 90% ;
                    border-collapse: collapse ;
                    margin-left: auto;
                    margin-right: auto;
                }
                caption {
                    color: white ; 
                    background-color: DarkSlateGrey ;
                }
                footer {
                    margin-top: 1em ;
                    width: 100% ;
                    text-align: center ;
                    color:  DimGrey ;
                }
                """;
        out.println( "<style>%s</style>".formatted( css ) );
        out.println( "<body>" );
        out.println( "<h1>" + message + "</h1>" );

        // Generate report from map data.
        StringBuilder table = new StringBuilder();
        String tableHeader =
                """
                <table>
                  <caption>Employee Day-of-Week Report</caption>
                """;
        table.append( tableHeader );
        Object attribute = this.getServletContext().getAttribute( "work.basil.example.employeeWorkDayAssigned" );
        Map < String, DayOfWeek > map = ( Map < String, DayOfWeek > ) attribute; // Cast back to original type.
        for ( Map.Entry < String, DayOfWeek > entry : map.entrySet() )
        {
            String row =
                    """
                      <tr>
                        <td>%s</td>
                        <td>%s</td>
                      </tr>
                    """
                            .formatted(
                                    entry.getKey() ,
                                    entry.getValue().getDisplayName( TextStyle.FULL_STANDALONE , Locale.US )
                            );
            table.append( row );
        }
        table.append( "</table>" + "\n" );

        out.println( table.toString() );
        out.println( "<footer>Report generated %s</footer>".formatted( Instant.now().truncatedTo( ChronoUnit.MINUTES ).toString() ) );
        out.println( "</body></html>" );
    }

    public void destroy ( )
    {
        // No code needed here.
    }
}
```

Resulting page.

[image: screenshot of generate HTML page rendered in web browser]

The HTML behind that page.

```html
<html lang='en'>
<head>
<meta charset='UTF-8'>
<style>
table, th, td , caption {
    border: 0.5px solid DarkSlateGrey ;
}
table {
    width: 90% ;
    border-collapse: collapse ;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
caption {
    color: white ;
    background-color: DarkSlateGrey ;
}
footer {
    margin-top: 1em ;
    width: 100% ;
    text-align: center ;
    color:  DimGrey ;
}
</style>
<body>
<h1>Report</h1>
<table>
  <caption>Employee Day-of-Week Report</caption>
  <tr>
    <td>Carol</td>
    <td>Tuesday</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Bob</td>
    <td>Monday</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alice</td>
    <td>Wednesday</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<footer>Report generated 2022-03-20T06:32:00Z</footer>
</body></html>
```

---

Oops, looks like I forgot to put an initial line:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
```

… at the top of this generated HTML page. This tag is required in [HTML5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5). Its presence may signal a web browser to use standards mode rather than [“quirks” mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode).

Comment: Precisely the biggest part of the work is on the search engine part to apply certain concepts, the deployment does not need to be very sophisticated, just an html page with a form which passes a request to my program and displays the results in a basic html, I think it's not really complicated it's just that I don't know much about web servers so I'm a little stuck .

Comment: @Ray17K The whole point of Java Servlet technology is to make it very simple for you to write the core code of your business logic while leaving all the heavy-lifting of being a server to the Servlet container like Tomcat or Jetty. That is what the "-let" in "Servlet" means, a tiny bit of code that plugs into the much bigger web server handling the networking, HTTP, Request parsing, Response packaging, etc. As a Servlet developer, all those details are abstracted away for you.

Comment: Thank you, I know that servlets are very powerful components, it's just that I've never used them, I'll look into it with some tutorials to deploy my program .

Comment: @Ray17K If you are doing some a quick-and-dirty project for limited use, in-house on a trusted network, then you could use the `HttpServer` class. Just be aware of its limitations as noted in the JEP,  including a lack of focus on security. If you go that way, I suggest looking at the Java 18 version, as I imagine it is "new and improved" for that JEP. But if you have any intentions of serious deployment, learning about Servlets and Tomcat/Jetty will be worth your time and effort. Good luck.